# Update of Ubuntu 20.04 to version 22.04 (jammy)

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

One of the reasons for getting this error is that I wanted to switch from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10. I wanted to do this because I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for about a month and I didn't get any updates to a newer version. I wanted to take matters into my own hands because it started to irritate me and I used [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today?fbclid=IwAR1gTLWrnchsasXYXruLokbFitHEZSZz6lZcCmaON1a2IZ2w3W3W3W3W3). I took the first method from the shore, but I didn't think that it could be an update to the development version of the system that is yet to appear on the market. It didn't update to version 22.04 because it was suggested by the system after using the first method of this guide, so various bugs began to appear, such as even after trying to run Software & Updates I got this message:

After typing in sudo apt-get update in the terminal, I got something like this:

[image]

After starting the program, the Software updater shows something like this:

[image]

When I click update partially it shows:

[image]

When I press continue it appears, however when I click upgrade nothing happens. When I type `sudo apt-get upgrade` this shows up:

[image]

When trying to solve this problem, I decided to use [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-update-error/). The error I am writing about is described in point 7.

Comment: your easiest option now may well be to download the 21.10 iso and install from USB or DVD preserving your current files **but do make sure you have good backups of anything important before doing so**

Comment: Reinstall 21.10. There is no official upgrade path other from LTS to LTS (18.04->20.04->21.04) or from each releases (20.04->20.10->21.04->21.10). It is far easier to set your system up such that you can reinstall every 6 month; just requires separating your content and the system; and if you install lots of software an post-install script.

Comment: I forgot to add that everything is virtualbox. Is it possible to just roll back these changes after this failed update without reinstalling the system? I am a beginner when it comes to computer science, but I do not want to limit myself to reinstalling the system each time (whether it is the current or new version)

Comment: I am confused by this question. Why bother to fix/restore/rollback a VM that you broke by doing something unwise? If you want a working system, then backup your data and install 21.04 into a new VM. If you want to learn about the breakage (or play), then you should have taken a VM Snapshot before you broke it. If you want to try to "roll back" or address a specific error, then we need to know the details of the error. However, fixing an entire system one-package-at-a-time might take you days. That's why the other two (faster) methods exist.

Comment: If you are using virtualbox take a snapshot before performing risky operations. It's too late, of course, if you have already done it before taking the snapshot.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has two intended upgrade paths; (1) to the next release - ie. 20.10 but it's EOL so that path is gone, or (2) to the next LTS after 22.04.1 has been released; not yet open.   The path (1) is still possible, but that's to the next supported release; which currently is 21.04. As it's not the intended 20.10 (that was missed), some problems may occur; but CI testing showed its possible (with no 3rd party apps). You're describing a path outside of supported, or tested paths for upgrade. Use supported paths if you want it to work cleanly & follow upgrade documentation

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImpishUpgrades

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *jammy* jellyfish [22.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu-next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is 21 April 2022](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906)) when your question will be on-topic here.

Comment: Okay okay. But then, if I had an update to the developer version after typing this sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3 command, why not update? Is there any command or a few to undo this? Ok, I understand that something like this takes time, but I must admit that I want to fix it, withdraw these changes somehow. I'm a Linux beginner but I'd like to change that. You can, for example, if not with the command, then run this linux in Live mode and fix it there somehow?

Comment: Withdrawing changes usually means restoring a backup you've previously created; how are we to know what backup strategy you use? or what file-system you've chosen to use? (some provide a *snapshot* reversal step for example if setup to do this). You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system (*flavors* too) without losing any user config, user file, and have it auto-install all *manually installed* packages (if from Ubuntu repositories) which is likely what I'd do in your case, but I stopped looking when I saw you were off-topic (*jammy*) as it's fast & easy, & great at resolving package issues...

Comment: I don't have a backup made. So you can reinstall ubuntu without losing data?

Comment: If you install (desktop) without format (*something else* or *manual partitioning* and select your existing partition(s) but do not format), it'll cause the installer to (1) note your installed package(s); ie. those you added or *manually installed*, (2) erase system directories, (3) install new system, (4) add back the *manually installed* packages noted earlier IF available in Ubuntu repositories for your new release, and (5) ask to reboot. No user file in $HOME (ie. your user directory) is touched IF you didn't format.  Of course you should backup first (just like before *release-upgrades*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Only I have it on virtualbox

Comment: Don't worry about loosing data. If you do not have a backup, then the data must not be important.

Comment: I'm not worried about the data. If you know any good tutorial that would help me solve this problem, please send it

Comment: Can I use Live CD mode in this case to fix this problem?

Comment: I wanted further help in solving the problem I presented, maybe it will be easier to solve it if it shows what needs to be updated. I decided to run sudo apt upgrade | tee file to see what exactly needs to be updated and at some point I got such a prompt [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7LAq.png. what should I choose specifically here. I am really asking seriously because I am not so advanced yet to know everything

Comment: Virtualbox simulates real hardware; so the only difference is you have to tell virtualbox you want to insert a floppy, cd, external drive in the host machine (& have it used by the VM); if it was a real machine the OS would deal with hardware (instead it deals with vbox which you control via settings). Virtualbox can do almost everything; but it can also stop things - you control what it allows/disallows on your *unstated* HOST. Pictures of text are harder to work on (we can't copy package names & enter into a CLI for queries on issues from a picture).

Comment: If unsure; why not re-install.  Ubuntu *jammy* (what will be 22.04 on release) is off-topic here; ISOs are available for QA-testing.  The `-d` option you used goes to development; in the blog you first references; 20.04 wasn't *stable* thus it was still the *development* version (20.04.1 hadn't been released which was [Aug 6](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule)); the *dev* version is now 22.04 so you should have guessed where it would have gone; if not reading the `man` (reference manual) page would have told you.  Thanks for testing *jammy jellyfish*, but it's off-topic here.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *jammy* jellyfish [22.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu-next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is 21 April 2022](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906)) when your question will be on-topic here.

Comment: Ok. But I just want to know what should be selected here. I just want to generate this file, but not interrupt the process that is running. If I select "Yes", will the computer restart?

Comment: never mind I handled it

Comment: But now I have another problem. Namely, I have updated the system to version 21.10, I do not know how it is possible, but it happened. I decided to turn it off for a moment and restart it because it was stuck terribly. Now, when I launch it, all I can see is a black screen with a blinking cursor. The Ubuntu logo appears normally and then suddenly a black screen and cursor. What could have happened? I don't know what's going on here but I decided to run a virtual console and I have something like that [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY7zA.png

Comment: I'd like to run this in graphics mode